# como extraer el indice de los datos de un json en php?

Tags: php, json, jsonobject

Buen día , poseo un json al cual deseo extraerle el indice , pero no tengo éxito porque no encuentro un método que me ayude.

este es mi código

```
<?php
require 'scraping/simple_html_dom.php';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('https://api.sunat.cloud/cambio/'.$año.'-'.$mes.'-24');

$date = json_decode($html,true);
echo $html;
```

este es la respuesta de mi consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask], editar y agregar tanto tu código como la salida que obtienes como texto y no como imagen

Comment: con el código no es problema , esto es lo que me devuelve una api , solo quiero como poder obtener ese indice ?

Comment: Precisamente requerimos tu avance para que de ahí alguien te pueda apoyar llevas tiempo en la plataforma ya deberías saber cómo funcionamos

Comment: añadí el código que uso , espero tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podriás mostrarnos el resultado de esto: `var_dump($date);` pulsa en [edit]  y agrégalo a la pregunta **en texto**, no en imagen. Incluso, se podría obtener desde el elemento `$html`. Muestra también un `var_dump($html;)`. Gracias.